# blender takes too long to transition between edit and object mode

Tags: workflow, vertices

I have made a funky cube with displace modifier with around 100 000 vertices, and blender suddenly takes around a minute or more just to change between edit and object mode, when saving, or going back(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>).
Screenshot of the object:

[image]

I noticed that when this freeze happens, my pc only uses 1 core of the processor to the fullest, and not the rest(16 cores).

i have
AMD Ryzen 2700,
16gb ram,
AMD Radeon R9

Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: modifier stack? not sure what you mean, but i have already applied the displace and only have a bevel modifier active

Comment: Modifier stack is where modifiers added to the object are shown until they are applied. Several modifiers can cause long response of Blender in some cases especially if object has several thousands faces and modifier generates more or edits them like Shrinkwrap. Anyway the question would benefit from several screenshots of the object and shown Properties editor with modifiers

Comment: Use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136484/edit) to add screenshots.

Comment: Include screenshots in the question body please. Likely it's due to modifier in the stack which is calculated each time you travel between interaction modes. Although from your screenshot it looks like you enabled Mesh Analysis (Edit mode > Properties shelf > Mesh Analysis rollout). It is running checks of the mesh which you might not need so try to disable it.

Comment: After i applied the bevel modifier everything went to normal, and i had not Mesh Analysis enabled. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As well as i know thw answer is 'no' . for the moment (3.5) in one object blender cant handle geometry after the treshold of 80 000-100 000 faces. This is a terminal problem of blender, maybe in future relesases they will do something about editmode performance beyond 100 000 face per objects. For this reason lot of people is seperating the geometry into smaller objects to work with in the edit mode. This is not a solution of course but right now this is the only solution. Maybe a very top computer with cpu ryzen 9 7950 could work a little  faster, but it is not a hardwar ware problem.